# C# Visual Studio TargetPlatform macro

Tags: c#, macros, post-build-event, post-build

We´ve got some thrid party c++ dll´s which are either x64 or x86. Now we want to write a post build script, which copies the x86 dll´s into target directory, if the targetplatform is x86 or the other way around. Our script looks like:

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)Lib\$(PlatformName)\*.*" "$(TargetDir)" /e /y /i
```

But the `$(PlatformName)`always is `AnyCpu`.
We also found `$(PlatformShortName)` but its always empty.

Does some one know the right macro? Or even better the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. Create a TargetPlatform with Configuration Manager and switch from AnyCpu to x86 or x64, then restart VS.